What does "coming" refer to in the context of Gwen’s conversation with Miguel and Jess?
Miguel criticizes Gwen for failing to stop Miles. He labels Gwen as a liability, and
despite Gwen’s protest, Jess agrees with him:

GWEN: Are you serious right now?
JESS: I told you, you let him get away, I can’t help you.
GWEN: I’m not coming.
MIGUEL: You’re right.

Miguel sends Gwen to her home.
What does "coming" refer to in the context of Gwen’s conversation with Miguel and Jess?

They plan on hunting down Miles. Gwen, who is his friend, refuses to join their hunt.

GWEN: I’m not coming [with you].

Miguel, who knows she is loyal to Miles, doesn't trust her and doesn't want her to join anyway.

MIGUEL: You’re right [that you're not coming with us].


I've edited out the commentary on the quality of the question. It's not needed for the answer and seems to have been largely intended to make the person asking feel bad.

@Valorum it was more of a note that he should be asking there, seeing a lot of his questions here are more about a language barrier than an actual plot point.

OP has received a very nice answer here from someone who's explained the context, having seen the film.
